# Drop down list with possibility to enter new value instead of list

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a small website php/mysql.
Let's say I have in my DB a table with different laptop specifications (brand, cpu, ...). When adding a new laptop in a html form, in the brand field for instance, I want to have the option to see all the distinct brands present in the DB and either choose one of them or add a new one. 
I am not necessarily looking for a code, maybe an idea.

I have 2 ideas so far:
1. I have a 'input' field where to write the brand name and a drop-down list right next to it, so if I choose a brand from the list, using javascript I think, the brand name will be filled in the input field automatically. Not the prettiest solution.

2. I don't know if there is such an option in html to add brand names somewhere in the code (a little bit like option/select) so when I double click in the input field I can see the list of brands then choose one or just type a new brand in.

3. Your idea/solution...

Comment: What kinda browser support do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need amazing browser support, you can use HTML 5 datalists (see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist). Have a look here for a few polyfills for it http://html5please.com/#datalist.

If you do, you should check out some of the million + JS implementations. I think jQueryUI might have one.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. Too bad that I can't rate your answer since I'm a new user.

Comment: @Rossygnol you can select it as your chosen answer if you want... it's just the check mark under the up/down arrows next to my answer.

Comment: this doesn't work reliably on Chrome  63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit) - Even the Mozilla pages loses the list entries once one has been selected

Answer (score 0):

create a table 'laptops' and display dropdown from the table

```
$laptopquery = mysql_query("select * from laptops");

<select name="laptop">
 <?php
  while($laptops = mysql_fetch_array($laptopquery)){
    print "<option value=\"".$laptops['laptop_id']."\">".$laptops['laptop_name']."</option>";
  }
 ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Which covers part of what OP wants. What about adding a new option into database?